# Passing an event from a custom component to a parent

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom component that extends a JComponent. When you click it, it catches the event with a MouseListener. Depending on the state of the component and where you click, the data stored in it updates.

**How can I notify the parent container when this happens while keeping it completely self-contained?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Myself, I would use the PropertyChangeSupport that comes with JComponent, and then fire your notify method whenever the program's state changes.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PropChangeEg {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final JLabel counterLabel = new JLabel(" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);

      CustomComponent myCustomComponent = new CustomComponent();
      myCustomComponent.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (pcEvt.getPropertyName().equals(CustomComponent.COUNTER)) {
               String text = "Counter: " + pcEvt.getNewValue();
               counterLabel.setText(text);
            }
         }
      });

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("PropChangeEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(myCustomComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(counterLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CustomComponent extends JComponent {
   public static final String COUNTER = "counter";
   private int counter = 0;

   public CustomComponent() {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Increment Counter") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setCounter(counter + 1);
         }
      }));
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Decrement Counter") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setCounter(counter - 1);
         }
      }));
   }

   //@Override // not needed!!
   //public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
   //   super.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   //}

   //@Override // not needed!!
   //public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
   //   super.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   //}

   public void setCounter(int counter) {
      int oldValue = this.counter;
      int newValue = counter;
      this.counter = newValue;
      firePropertyChange(COUNTER, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public int getCounter() {
      return counter;
   }


}
```

Regarding comments:

A ChangeListener will work fine too. 1+ to user129... but what I like about PCL is that I can specify the names of properties to listen for allowing me to listen to the changes of multiple different states and this way can create a complete View from a MVC design that is completely decoupled from the Control. So my recommendation is: if you're only listening to one state, then by all means use a ChangeListener, but if you're listening to multiple states, use a PCL.

Comment: sure, or just implement ChangeListener

Comment: @user: yep, as long as we minimize coupling, I'm happy.

Comment: Actually my bad, if extending JComponent, there's no need to create my own add or remove PCL since it comes with the super. I'm so used to extending by composition where this is necessary.

Comment: I've tried PropertyChangeSupport before, but it felt very clunky to implement. Luckily, however...
@user1291492 - ChangeListener worked perfectly, so if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Tharwen: That will work fine too. 1+ to user129... What I like about PCL is that I can specify the names of properties to listen for and this way can create a complete View from a MVC design that is completely decoupled from the Control. So my recommendation is: if you're only listening to one state, then by all means use a ChangeListener, but if you're listening to multiple states, use a PCL.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ChangeListener it should work for you